# azure cognitive search - dynamically adding blobs for azure search rest api

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have multiple containers with blobs(.xlsx format) in it, how can I use one azure search service so that on each rest api call I can get sum of count of a column from each blob or all blobs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an out-of-the-box way to do this.

A few suggestions:

1. If you are reading blobs using the Azure blob SDK (not using
   built-in indexers), you would have to extract the Excel data and
   compute the count (examples of how to get the Excel data with .NET
   [are
   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571011/how-do-i-read-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-without-missing-any-columns))
2. If you are using [pull blob indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage)
   you can either:

- Use [Azure AI Document Intelligence (Form Recognizer) custom
  skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-form-recognizer-custom-skill-for-azure-cognitive-search/)
  to get the data from tabular form and then in the custom skill do
  some calculations for the count.
- From a [custom
  skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-interface)
  as well, get the data using a library that reads from Excel and then
  index.

Here is a [repo of Power Skills](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills) (custom skills applied to different use cases) in case you need examples of how to use them and the [skillset official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-working-with-skillsets)